# Triple Integral With Spherical Coordinates - Napkin Ring?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates

I wish to calculate the integral bellow, where $T$ is the region bounded by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4.$ It looks to me that it represents a Napkin ring.
$$\iiint_T\bigl(x^2 + y^2\bigr)\,\text{d}V.$$
The answer is $\dfrac{\bigl(256 - 132\sqrt{3}\,\bigr)\pi}{15}.$

Comment: Your specification is ambiguous.  Do you mean $x^2 + y^2 \geq 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4$?  Or $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4$?  From your "napkin ring" description, I assume it's the first option, but [one of the answers below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413347/248639) assumes the second option.

Comment: Well, sorry for the ambiguity. I was just taking a guess about the shape, a terrible one it seems, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $T$ is ambiguous (see also Michael Seifert's comment). According to given answer, $T$ should be the union of two spherical caps and a cylinder:
$$T=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2 + y^2 \leq  1,\;x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4\}.$$
Note that we can split the integral in two:
$$\iiint_T\bigl(x^2 + y^2\bigr)\,\text{d}V=2(I_1+I_2)$$
where
$$I_1=\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/6}\left(\int_{r=0}^2\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}(r\sin(\phi))^2\cdot r^2\sin(\phi)\,d\theta\right)dr\right)d\phi$$
and
$$
I_2=\int_{\phi=\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\left(\int_{r=0}^{1/\sin(\phi)}
\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}(r\sin(\phi))^2\cdot r^2\sin(\phi)\,d\theta\right)dr\right)d\phi.$$
Can you take it from here? Check the result with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*Pi*int(int(r%5E4*sin(t)%5E3,r%3D0..2),t%3D0..Pi%2F6)%20%2B4*Pi*int(int(r%5E4*sin(t)%5E3,r%3D0..1%2Fsin(t)),t%3DPi%2F6..Pi%2F2)).

P.S. The Napkin ring is given by
$$N:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2 + y^2 \geq  1,\;x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4\}.$$ 
and 
$$\iiint_N\bigl(x^2 + y^2\bigr)\,\text{d}V=2I_3=\frac{132\sqrt{3}\pi}{15}$$
where
$$
I_3=\int_{\phi=\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\left(\int_{r=1/\sin(\phi)}^{r=2}
\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}(r\sin(\phi))^2\cdot r^2\sin(\phi)\,d\theta\right)dr\right)d\phi.$$

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is the right region of integration;  see my comment on the question, above.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I agree with your comment. Th definition of $T$ is ambiguous. Anyway, I checked and the second option gives the correct answer.

Comment: Well, I would like to know how you found φ = π/6 as upper bound, and also, I didn't quite understand why the upper bound of r is equal to 1/sin(φ) in the second integral.

Comment: @Lucas Lemos Draw a section that is the intersection of a circle $x^2+y^2=2^2$ with the parallelel lines $x=-1$ and $x=1$. Consider the intersection of point $P=(1,\sqrt{3})$. The angle between the $y$-axis and $OP$ is equal to $\phi=\pi/6$.

Comment: @Lucas Lemos $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ implies $r\sin(\phi)\leq 1$.

Comment: @Lucas Lemos Any further doubt?

Comment: Two more, thanks. Considering the infinite coordinates you could find to x² + y² = 2², why did you used (1,√3) to find ϕ?. And, How did you find the upper bound of the second integral  ϕ =  π/2?

Comment: @LucasLemos Since the integral is symmetric $\phi$ varies from $0$ (north pole) to  $\pi/2$ (the equator) and then the result is doubled. As regards $I_2$ you could also integrate from $\pi/6$ to $5\pi/6$ (without doubling).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, could you please try again?
You took P = (1,√3).
arctg(1/√3) = 30º. Okay I get it. But, P = (2, 0) is also a solution to the equation, and it doesn't give 30º as an angle.
And for the boundaries π/6 to π/2 for ϕ, I couldn't keep up with the explanation as well. Sorry for this inconvenience, probably the answer is under my nose and I'm too blind to see it.

Comment: @LucasLemos $P=(1,\sqrt{3})$ Is given by the intersection of $x^2+y^2=2^2$ and $x=1$ (we are considering the intersection of the sphere of radius $2$ and the cylinder of radius $1$) . Moreover for $\phi\in [0,\pi/6]$ we are drawing an arc of radius $r=2$. For $\phi\in [\pi/6,\pi/2]$ we are drawing a line $x=r\sin(\phi)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the region is the interior, and not the napkin ring.

converting to cylindrical

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r^3 \ dz\ dr\ d\theta$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2r^3\sqrt{4-r^2} \ dr\ d\theta\\
r^2=4-u^2 ,\ 2r\ dr = -2u\ du\\
\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_\sqrt{3}^{2} 2(4-u^2)u^2 \ du\ d\theta\\
(4\pi)(\frac 43 u^3 - \frac 15 u^5 )|_\sqrt{3}^2\\
(4\pi)(\frac {64}{15} - \frac {33\sqrt {3}}{15})\\
$